# Reading files with libgit2

Tags: libgit2

I was diving in libgit2 few days ago, and did read some snippets on their samples. But I was wondering if there is a way reading files on a remote git repo without downloading it? Ijust wanna get out the filenames and read the content without donwloading them locally. Is there any possibility to do so or did I oversee that? Or maybee misunderstood something in the API?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.  This is not part of the git protocol; per git, you need to clone the repository if you want to read a file.

If you want to read a file from a remote hosting provider, like GitHub, you will need to use [their API](https://octokit.github.io/).